# Not getting token in the response from the react app.js fetch

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am linking django to react.

I am trying to get the token from a Django-rest-framework endpoint http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-token which is using a tokenAuthentication, from react app.js .
I have set up corsheaders and restframework all that. when I hit the endpoint through the command line with a token it works. Now I need the token in my react app.js. I get a response with status 200 but I can't find the token. As I am new to react I am not sure if I am missing something.
//App.js

```
  componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const data = {username: 'user', password: 'password'};
      fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-token/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.token);
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Let me know if you need more info

I have tried both TokenAuthentication and BasicAuthentication in my settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `response.data.token`? Or log the whole response and check what you get, to verify that the token is present

Comment: Response {type: "cors", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-token/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers
__proto__: Headers
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-token/"
__proto__: Response

This is the response I am getting. I don't think it has the token.
when I try response.data.token
App.js:20 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined
    at App.js:20
I get this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using fetch, you first have to [read the response stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) using `.response.json()`.

This is your code example with an extra `then` after the fetch, to return a new promise containing your data (parsed with JSON):

```js
 componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const data = {username: 'user', password: 'password'};
      fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-token/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data.token);
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Note: if the data you receive from the server is not JSON, you should use `response.text()` to just parse the response as a string.

Comment: So now that I am getting the token can I use the same format to hit the api endpoint where I am trying to get the serialized data from?
```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/testbuildingtype', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authentication': 'Token ' + token
        }
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
      })
```

Comment: @DaminiGanesh yes, that should work. You should always read the response stream using either `.text()` or `.json()` to access the data using fetch.

Comment: But I get this error now
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/testbuildingtype' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authentication is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
I tried both .text() and .json()

Comment: @DaminiGanesh that's a whole different issue. You should check out https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/